# Clarify definition of the isometry used in proving $C[0,1]$ and $C[a,b]$ are isometric.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

> Prove $C[0,1]$ and $C[a,b]$ are isometric.

We are using the max-norm
**My attempt was:**
I have to show that there is an distance-preserving bijection between the spaces

I define: $T:C[0,1]\to C[a,b]$ by

$Tf(t)=f(a(1-t)+bt) \forall t \in [0,1] $

$Tf(t)=f(x) \forall x \in [a,b] $  This should be the same right?

**However  the student tutor defined it like this:**

$T:C[0,1]\to C[a,b]$ by $Tf(t)=f(\frac{t-a}{b-a}) \forall t \in [a,b] $

Of course  $a(1-t)+bt$ and  $\frac{t-a}{b-a}$ are inverse of each other,but **I am very confused about why it is my definition not ok,the order in which it should be done is confusing me.  I then proved linearity and bijectivity and everything seemed to work just as with the tutor's definition. Can someone please elaborate on this?**

Comment: The question makes no sense if you do not tell us which distances you are using in those spaces.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos We are using the max norm, it is not specified in my sheet, but the prof said it is taken like that when not specified, I didn't know it was only an in-class convention

Answer (score 2):

For $f \in C[0,1]$, $Tf$ is supposoed to be an element of $C[a,b]$. So we have to define $Tf(t)$ for $a \leq t \leq b$. Instead you have tried to define it for $0 \leq t \leq1 $. Note that $a \leq t \leq b$ implies $0 \leq \frac {t-a} {b-a} \leq 1$ so $f(\frac {t-a} {b-a})$ is well-defined.

Comment: Since $a(1-t)+bt$  sends $[0,1]$ into $[a,b]$ Can't  I write  $f(a(1-t)+bt)=f(x), x \in [a,b]$? The reason I am writting like this is that the suggestion of the problem says to define T as a change of variable. So if I keep the same t there it wouldn't be a change of variable , would it ? (both in $f(a(1-t)+bt$ and $f( (t-a)/(b-a))$ )

Comment: @J.C.VegaO You defined $Tf(t)$ as $f(a(1-t)+bt) \forall t \in [0,1]$. Is this defined when $t=0$?. Remember that $f \in C[0,1]$, so $f(x)$ makes sense only for $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO If you want to define a map$T: [0,1] \to [a,b]$ then $T(t)=a(1-t)+bt$ works fine. But that is not what we are doing here.

Comment: How is that different? I see your point in the first comment, but it seems so natural to think that if I have a map between the domains I have a map between the functions in the same order

Comment: It gives  a map between the function spaces in the reverse order!

Answer (score 1):

It helps to think of the following commutative diagram

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
[0,1] & \stackrel{g}{\longleftarrow} & [a,b] \\
\downarrow{f} & & \downarrow{f'} \\
\mathbb{R} & \stackrel{\mathrm{Id}}{\longrightarrow} & \mathbb{R}  
\end{array}.
$$

Given $f$, you want to find $f'$. Well, to do that, you just compose $f' = \mathrm{Id}  \circ f \circ g = f \circ g$.

Notice that the domain of $g$ is $[a,b]$ and codomain $[0,1]$ so you want $g$ to be a rescaling of the interval $[a,b]$ into $[0,1]$. The most obvious choice then is to make $g(t) = \frac{t-a}{b-a}$.

So, given $f$, we define $f'$ to be $f \circ g$ which for an element $t \in [a,b]$ is $f(\frac{t-a}{b-a})$.

That is, $$T(f)(t) =  f\left(\frac{t-a}{b-a}\right).$$

Just as a tip for future. Often, when trying to find mappings like this, it helps to draw the diagram of what you know, what you need, and how you get from what you know to what you need (as we did above).

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful, just one thing when I write $T(f)(t) =  f(\frac{t-a}{b-a})$, If I do $x=\frac{t-a}{b-a}$ then $T(f)(t) =  f(x)$ ,$ x\in [0,1]$, and since variables are just placeholders $T(f)(t) =  f(t)$ , $t\in[0,1]$ . It seems like  what $T$ does nothing to $f$, but  Is this a correct way to write it?

Comment: Even without changing $x$ to $t$, $T$ transforms $f(t)$ defined on $[0,1]$ to $f(x)$ defined on $[0,1]$ HOw do I make sense of it?

Comment: "and since variables are just placeholders". This is incorrect reasoning. $x$, as you've defined it, is dependant on $t$. You can't just replace it with $t$.